# HTML/PHP scripting - redirect to a new webpage after validation

Tags: php, html

I am using something similar to the following code to log a user in and redirect that user to a new web page once they are logged in:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<title>application</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
<div id="LoginPage">
<form method="GET" action="validateLogin.php">
<table style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 0;">
    <tr>
       <td align="right" bgcolor="#3333FF"><p id="text">Trader Id:</p></td>
       <td align="left" bgcolor="#3333FF">
     <input type="text" name="user">
   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="right" bgcolor="#3333FF"><p id="text">Password:</p></td>
       <td align="left" bgcolor="#3333FF"><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
             <input type="hidden" size="50" value="<?php echo $var; ?>"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><p id="text"></p></td>
       <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><p id="text"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><p id="text"></p></td>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#B3B3B3"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED**

PHP

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username=$username");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
  echo 1; 
} else {
  echo -1; 
}
```

My PHP validation script (validateLogin.php) returns 1 if the user is logged in and -1 if they do not have an account. How can I modify this script so that when the user logs in, and logs in successfully, they are redirected to a new page rather than being shown the -1 or 1 return?

Comment: I should point out that $var is the variable name for the return from the PHP script.

Comment: The code you're showing is the HTML code. The logic and redirection should be done in PHP so can you show us the PHP code. And the function used to redirect is header("Location:FILENAME.php");

Comment: I can't give you the exact code but it is roughly:             `$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE    username=$username");

      if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
      {
          echo 1;
      }

      else
      {
          echo -1;
      }`

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username=$username");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1){
   header('Location:success.php'); //Login successfull
}else{
   header('Location:login.php'); //Login failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $var > 0 ) header('Location:success.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this into your condition

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
  header('Location:success.php');
} else {
  header('Location:login.php');
}
```